# How to translate dates in QT?

Tags: qt, qtranslate, qt5.7

I would like to make a label with the date written on it in many languages. How can I translate it from english to the choosen language? Like this:

English:`Thursday, 1 January 1970`

Arabic:`۱۹۷۰ الخميس, ۱ يناير`

The code I used to get the date is:

```
QLabel *Time = new QLabel(QDate::currentDate().toString(Qt::SystemLocaleLongDate));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [QLocale](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html) in order to convert a [QDate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html) to string.
This could be acheived like this :

```
    QLocale locale = QLocale(QLocale::Arabic, QLocale::Egypt);
    QString arabicDate = locale.toString(QDate::currentDate());
```